# Node.js server does not respond externally

Tags: centos7, http, node.js

I made a simple node.js server:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(9999, '0.0.0.0');
console.log('Server running at post 9999');
```

it works outputting:

`Server running at port 9999`

yet I **can't reach it at VPS/VDS IP** where the code is residing: http://185.221.154.249:9999/
**Why is that**?

Does it matter what location inside of my VDS (centos 7) the code is located?

Note: My domain is tied to that IP and works well at post 443: https://webscraping.pro/ (blog on WP is there)

Comment: Are you sure that is the code you are actually running? You should copy and paste it to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you encounter is with the **ports not allowed by Firewall**. Please set up the firewall setting to allow port 9999, make it open. If you're not able to do that ask a hosting support to help with it.
What control panel do you use?

### Update:

[image]

Comment: I use **Vesta CP**.

Comment: @IgorSavinkin see my update.